# How can I prevent reordering of items in a user's main playlists container?

Tags: sonos

I am implementing user playlists by following [this instruction](https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-add-features/add-playlists/). I don't want to allow the items in the main playlists container to be reordered, so I have set `canReorderItems="false"` like this:

```
<ns1:mediaCollection readOnly="false" canReorderItems="false" canDeleteItems="true" userContent="true">
  <ns1:id>playlists</ns1:id>
  <ns1:itemType>playlist</ns1:itemType>
  <ns1:displayType>list</ns1:displayType>
  <ns1:title>Playlists</ns1:title>
  <ns1:canPlay>false</ns1:canPlay>
  <ns1:albumArtURI></ns1:albumArtURI>
</ns1:mediaCollection>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to have any effect. When I browse into the Playlists container I am still allowed to reorder items and a `reorderContainer` request is sent to my service.

[image]

What is the correct way of preventing reordering of items in a user's main playlists container?

Comment: This may be a bug. I'm investigating with the Engineering team and will post an answer once resolved.

Answer (score 0):

We don't support the `canReorderItems` `mediaCollection` property. I'll update the [Add playlists](https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-add-features/add-playlists/) and [SMAPI object types `mediaCollection`](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/types/smapi-object-types/#mediaCollection) documentation.

Comment: But you do support reordering mediaCollections, so there is no way to prevent a user from doing what's shown in the screenshot above?

Comment: Sonos doesn't support disabling reordering when "userContent=true".